# Scala filter tuples (x, y) == (y, x)

Tags: scala, filter

I have a list of tuples, for example:

```
  (0,2)
  (0,5)
  (2,0)
  (2,5)
  (3,4)
  (4,3)
  (5,0)
  (5,2)
```

There are some tuples where `(x, y) == (y, x)`, for example (5, 0) and (0, 5). I want to leave just one of them, for example first one. How can I do it?

Comment: What should happen for (2,2), and for (2,3) (2,3) (3,2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using foldLeft

```
var ts = List((0,2),  (0,5),  (2,0), (2,5),  (3,4), (4,3), (5,0), (5,2))  

ts.foldLeft(List[(Int,Int)]())
   {(acc, el) => if ((acc contains el) || (acc contains el.swap)) acc else el::acc}
// List[(Int, Int)] = List((3,4), (2,5), (0,5), (0,2))
```

Or, with Sets for an O(n) version (assuming Set lookup and additions are O(1))

```
ts.foldLeft(Set[(Int,Int)]()){(acc, el) => if (acc(el.swap)) acc else acc + el}
```

If it doesn't matter if we re-order ones where the swapped tuple is not present (I'm guessing it doesn't as you don't specify which of the ones that have a swapped tuple should be kept):

```
ts.map{t => if (t._1 < t._2) t else t.swap}.distinct
// List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,2), (0,5), (2,5), (3,4))
```

Comment: Ow, `O(n^2)` runtime!

Comment: Second algo has O(n) complexity, because distinct based on hashset.

Comment: Or use a Set for the first one. The List allows easy modification for (for example) keeping duplicates, though, and preserves ordering

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupBy` the tuples represented as a `Set`, which will make `Set(0, 5) == Set(5, 0)`, etc. Then `map` the resulting `Map` to the groups of tuples and convert it back to a `List`, and finally grab the `head` of each list for one representative of the group. Calling `head` is ok here, because the groups will never be empty (they would otherwise just not be there at all).

```
val list = List((0,2), (0,5), (2,0), (2,5), (3,4), (4,3), (5,0), (5,2))

list.groupBy { case (x, y) => Set(x, y) } // Map[Set, List[(Set, (Int, Int))]]
    .map(_._2)                            // Iterable[List[(Int, Int)]] 
    .toList                               // List[List[(Int, Int)]]
    .map(_.head)                          // List[(Int, Int)]


res10: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,5), (3,4), (2,5), (0,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about first sorting the tuple pairs internally.  I believe this technique would pass through your list just twice since *distinct* is advertised as O(n) complexity:

```
val ts = List((0,2),(0,5),(2,0),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,0),(5,2))

ts.map{ case (x,y) if x < y => (y,x) case (x,y) => (x,y) }.distinct
```