# RDD Product without repeat some tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I got the following RDD[String]

```
TTT
SSS
AAA
```

and I am having problems to get the following tuples

```
(TTT, SSS)
(TTT, AAA)
(SSS, AAA)
```

I was doing:

```
val res = input.cartesian(input).filter{ case (a,b) => a != b }
```

But the result is:

```
(TTT,SSS)
(TTT,AAA)
(SSS,TTT)
(SSS,AAA)
(AAA,TTT)
(AAA,SSS)
```

What is the best way to do that? please

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order of the elements in the RDD?

Comment: No, it is not necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spark: produce RDD\[(X, X)\] of all possible combinations from RDD\[X\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557873/spark-produce-rddx-x-of-all-possible-combinations-from-rddx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could impose an order in the tuple to obtain the combinations:

```
val res = input.cartesian(input).filter{ case (a,b) => a < b }
```

Comment: Or, if you can't filter them as you create them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26917151/21755. This is at least the third question that basically ask the same thing - is this from some course assignment? (just curious)

Comment: And that RDD is: `TTT, AAA, TTT, SSS`. To get a new RDD as `(TTT, SSS), (TTT, AAA), (SSS, AAA) (TTT, TTT)` =/ ?

Comment: @Paul not my case. Really my RDDs are more complex than that.

Comment: How does that complexity make things different? (again, just curious, if @maasg's answer works, that's good!)